# How to draw border in QTableWidgetItem?

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyside2

My purpose is to draw borders in the particular QTableWidgetItem when I need, which are editable by double click.

I have the following problems;

1. The QTableWidgetItem does not use 'setStyleSheet' function.
2. I insert the changed QLabel style into the QTableWidgetItem, but it cannot be edited by double click
3. I tried to use a pixmap to draw it according to the size of the QTableWidgetItem, but I don't know the size of QTableWidgetItem.

I can't find the answer on how to draw the border.

[image]

(↑ Result that I want to)

```
import sys
from PySide2.QtGui import *
from PySide2.QtWidgets import *


class MyApp(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setGeometry(200, 300, 500, 500)

        # QTableWidget
        self.tableWidget = QTableWidget(self)
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(2)
        self.tableWidget.setMinimumSize(400, 400)
        self.tableWidget.setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView.DoubleClicked)

        for i in range(3):
            self.tableWidget.insertRow(i)
            for j in range(2):
                print(i, j)
                self.tableWidget.setItem(i, j, QTableWidgetItem(QIcon(), '0'))

        # pushButton
        self.button = QPushButton(self)
        self.button.setGeometry(450, 450, 50, 50)
        self.button.setText('mark')
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.markItem)
        self.show()

    def markItem(self) -> None:
        label = QLabel()
        label.setStyleSheet('border: 3px solid yellow;')

        tableWidgetItem = self.tableWidget.currentItem()
        row = tableWidgetItem.row()
        col = tableWidgetItem.column()
        self.tableWidget.setCellWidget(row, col, label)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MyApp()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

(↑ insert QLabel into QTableWidgetItem. but is not editable.)

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "when I need to". Also, QTableWidget already supports editing items, so it's unclear what you're trying to do with a QLabel (which is normally not editable). Please clarify what you're doing and provide a valid [mre] of your attempts, as your description is not sufficient.

Comment: @musicamante sorry.. I add my test cod. This meaning of 'when needed to' is always when I can change a particular the QTableWidgetItem when I want to. It is not necessary to apply to all items just by changing the style sheet of qtablewidget.

Comment: You need a custom item delegate, override its [`paint()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyleditemdelegate.html#paint) function, call the base implementation, and eventually draw the border based on a defined context (for example by using `setData()` on the "selected" item). You cannot use stylesheets because QTableWidgeItems are not widgets, and you should not use index widgets for that, as that's not their purpose. Do some research about item delegates in Qt, there are lots of posts and resources on the subject.